# API Data undefined when used in the component

Tags: angular, typescript, api, get, undefined

i have this service to get data from the api and save it into arrays afterwards:

```
export class DataService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

readonly baseURL = "https://localhost:44302/api";
books: Book[];
users: User[];
cards: Card[];
postId: number;

httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  })
}

getBooks() {
  return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/books');
}
getCards() {
  return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/cards');
}
getUsers() {
  return this.http.get(this.baseURL + '/users');
} 
getData() {
  const observableList: Observable<any>[] = [];

  observableList.push(this.getBooks());
  observableList.push(this.getUsers());
  observableList.push(this.getCards());

  forkJoin(observableList).subscribe(resultList => {
    this.books = resultList[0] as Book[];
    this.users = resultList[1] as User[];
    this.cards = resultList[2] as Card[];
  });
}
```

in my component, i run the getData method and try to console.log the data but it keeps saying that the data is undefined, even though the api data shows up in the debugging-network tab:

```
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {
books: Book[];
users: User[];
cards: Card[];
selectedBook: Book;
display: boolean = false;
selectedUser: User;

constructor(public dataService: DataService) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataService.getData();
  //Save data in local component arrays
  this.books = this.dataService.books;
  this.users = this.dataService.users;
  this.cards = this.dataService.cards;

  console.log(this.books); // ==> "undefined"
  }
```

Comment: You really don’t want to subscribe in your service. Best thing to do is have your service return the forkJoin so return forkJoin(observableList) and subscribe to that in your component

Comment: alright thanks Mike. So in the service i just do 
`return forkJoin(observableList);"`
and on my component i say:
` 
this.dataService.getData.subscribe((result) => {
   this.books = resultList[0] as Book[];
    this.users = resultList[1] as User[];
    this.cards = resultList[2] as Card[];
}`

Comment: I just tried it, it keeps saying "undefined"

Answer (score 2):

The arrays assigned within the component (after the service call) will already be executed before the service with *getData()* completes subscribing to the three observables. That is why they are assigning to undefined data.

In your service, modify it to return just the observable:

```
getData() {
  const observableList: Observable<any>[] = [];

  observableList.push(this.getBooks());
  observableList.push(this.getUsers());
  observableList.push(this.getCards());

  return forkJoin(observableList);
}
```

In your component then subscribe to the joined data calling *getDate()* within a subscriber:

```
this.dataService.getData()
  .subscribe(({resultOne, resultTwo, resultThree}) => {
     //Save data in local component arrays
     this.books = resultOne;
     this.users = resultTwo;
     this.cards = resultThree;
  });
}
```

Comment: thanks andrew! Now i can do a console.log(result) in the .subscribe block and it shows the data. But if i want to use the data  outside the .subscribe block for example console.log(this.books) it still says undefined. How am i able to send the received data to another service and modify it, when the data is undefined? Or do i have to do everything in the subscribe block?

Comment: You can either fire another observable (use a Subject or a BehaviorSubject) within the subscribe() { .. } block and subscribe to it with another subscription in ngInit() or call the other services through a user-triggered event handler within your component. This way you can process the results after they are received within your component.